# How to solve Laravel 504 Gateway Time-out

Tags: laravel, api, nginx, connection-timeout, http-status-code-504

I am trying to send images to WooCommerce through API and I am getting `504 Gateway Time-out`, the same error I am getting in Postman. I tried with changing max_execution_time but again I got error 504.

```
  public function updateProduct($ecart, $product, $wooId){

        //set_time_limit(3600); 
        //ini_set('max_execution_time', 3600);
        //ini_set('memory_limit', '2048M');
        $response = Http::withHeaders([
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
            ])->withBasicAuth($ecart->client_key, $ecart->client_secret)->put(
            $ecart->url.'/wp-json/wc/v3/products/'.$wooId,
            $product);
            //dd($response);
            dump('res',$response);
            $body = json_decode($response->getBody(), true);
           dd($body);

        return $response;

    }
```

What else I can do, because I have this problem in localhost, adn I don't know will this happen in production??

This is my response

```
Illuminate\Http\Client\Response^ {#9529
  #response: GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response^ {#9583
    -reasonPhrase: "Gateway Time-out"
    -statusCode: 504
    -headers: array:6 [
      "Server" => array:1 [
        0 => "nginx"
      ]
      "Date" => array:1 [
        0 => "Fri, 27 Jan 2023 08:08:48 GMT"
      ]
      "Content-Type" => array:1 [
        0 => "text/html"
      ]
      "Content-Length" => array:1 [
        0 => "160"
      ]
      "Connection" => array:1 [
        0 => "keep-alive"
      ]
      "Strict-Transport-Security" => array:1 [
        0 => "max-age=63072000"
      ]
    ]
    -headerNames: array:6 [
      "server" => "Server"
      "date" => "Date"
      "content-type" => "Content-Type"
      "content-length" => "Content-Length"
      "connection" => "Connection"
      "strict-transport-security" => "Strict-Transport-Security"
    ]
    -protocol: "1.1"
    -stream: GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream^ {#9580
      -stream: stream resource {@1032
        wrapper_type: "PHP"
        stream_type: "TEMP"
        mode: "w+b"
        unread_bytes: 0
        seekable: true
        uri: "php://temp"
        options: []
      }
      -size: null
      -seekable: true
      -readable: true
      -writable: true
      -uri: "php://temp"
      -customMetadata: []
    }
  }
  #decoded: null
  +"cookies": GuzzleHttp\Cookie\CookieJar^ {#9554
    -cookies: []
    -strictMode: false
  }
  +"transferStats": GuzzleHttp\TransferStats^ {#9584
    -request: GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request^ {#9577
      -method: "PUT"
      -requestTarget: null
      -uri: GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Uri^ {#9553
        -scheme: "https"
        -userInfo: ""
        -host: "test.myraidbox.de"
        -port: null
        -path: "/wp-json/wc/v3/products/10612"
        -query: ""
        -fragment: ""
        -composedComponents: "https://test.myraidbox.de/wp-json/wc/v3/products/10612"
      }
      -headers: array:5 [
        "Content-Length" => array:1 [
          0 => "1902"
        ]
        "User-Agent" => array:1 [
          0 => "GuzzleHttp/7"
        ]
        "Authorization" => array:1 [
          0 => "Basic Y2tfYWY4MTFhZmU4OWM2OWNjMWRjY2NiMGRlYjVmYjc2Y2UyODQxYTUyNzpjc182ZThkODlhZDIzNTVlYjA1ZTJhOTY5YThkODE3ZmQ4NWQ0NjY3MDA2"
        ]
        "Host" => array:1 [
          0 => "test.myraidbox.de"
        ]
        "Content-Type" => array:1 [
          0 => "application/json"
        ]
      ]
      -headerNames: array:5 [
        "content-length" => "Content-Length"
        "user-agent" => "User-Agent"
        "authorization" => "Authorization"
        "host" => "Host"
        "content-type" => "Content-Type"
      ]
      -protocol: "1.1"
      -stream: GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream^ {#9568
        -stream: stream resource {@1030
          wrapper_type: "PHP"
          stream_type: "TEMP"
          mode: "w+b"
          unread_bytes: 0
          seekable: true
          uri: "php://temp"
          options: []
        }
        -size: 1902
        -seekable: true
        -readable: true
        -writable: true
        -uri: "php://temp"
        -customMetadata: []
      }
    }
    -response: GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response^ {#9583}
    -transferTime: 30.163235
    -handlerStats: array:38 [
      "url" => "https://test.myraidbox.de/wp-json/wc/v3/products/10612"
      "content_type" => "text/html"
      "http_code" => 504
      "header_size" => 200
      "request_size" => 2195
      "filetime" => -1
      "ssl_verify_result" => 0
      "redirect_count" => 0
      "total_time" => 30.163235
      "namelookup_time" => 0.004224
      "connect_time" => 0.007388
      "pretransfer_time" => 0.103427
      "size_upload" => 1902.0
      "size_download" => 160.0
      "speed_download" => 5.0
      "speed_upload" => 63.0
      "download_content_length" => 160.0
      "upload_content_length" => 1902.0
      "starttransfer_time" => 30.163099
      "redirect_time" => 0.0
      "redirect_url" => ""
      "primary_ip" => "::ffff:167.235.133.93"
      "certinfo" => []
      "primary_port" => 443
      "local_ip" => "::ffff:172.18.0.7"
      "local_port" => 57572
      "http_version" => 2
      "protocol" => 2
      "ssl_verifyresult" => 0
      "scheme" => "HTTPS"
      "appconnect_time_us" => 103359
      "connect_time_us" => 7388
      "namelookup_time_us" => 4224
      "pretransfer_time_us" => 103427
      "redirect_time_us" => 0
      "starttransfer_time_us" => 30163099
      "total_time_us" => 30163235
      "appconnect_time" => 0.103359
    ]
    -handlerErrorData: 0
  }
}
```

And this is my `.docker/nginx/default`

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name backend.brandcanyon.de;
    root /var/www/html/public;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    ssl_certificate     /etc/ssl/certs/localhost.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/localhost.key;

    client_max_body_size 100M;

    fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
    proxy_read_timeout 600;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;

        # for OPTIONS return these headers and HTTP 200 status
        if ($request_method = OPTIONS) {
          add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods "*";
          add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers "*";
          add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*";
          return 200;
        }
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass php-fpm:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Comment: In your Http/Kernel.php check your api middleware. If your API is being throttled, the issue can sometimes arise from there and you will need to increase the throttle value. You can just check that file if everything is okay there.

Comment: The error is coming from the server you're talking _to_ i.e. `bahu019.myraidbox.de`.  You can't fix a 504 client side (your php code is the client here), unless the problem is that either you're talking to the wrong host or caused by something being wrong with the request. Does `bahu019.myraidbox.de` resolve to the right IP in that docker container (`"primary_ip" => "::ffff:167.235.133.93"` this _does_ suggest your request is reaching the intended server)?